# Required asterisk is not displayed in input fields Primefaces 6.0

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have created a form using Primefaces 6.0 and in the bean I have used constrained validators like `@NotNull` and `@NotEmpty` in the bean fields. However the asterisk near the label of the input text are not automatically rendered. The asterisk is only displayed when I set and an `inputText` as `"required=true"`. My problem is that I would like to use the validation messages provided by the bean validation JSR so I would not like to put "required"to the input texts. I have also read that after primefaces 5.0 the validation constraints are automatically detected and the asterisk is rendered automatically. Has anyone faced a similar problem? Have I missed any configuration?

Comment: can you put some code and image of your output

Answer (score 0):

i think whatever you want is possible by some custom code, use CSS for asterisk (*) in read color, do not put `required=true` use custom validate. have look https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csv/custom.xhtml

if you did not put `required=true` your form will submmited to bean and you have to check and bean level for validation.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my problem that it do not need custom validator since I dont have custom constraints.My problem is the asterisk rendering and I can not figure out why I need to use custom css, since it is highlighted that after primefaces 5.0 the regular constraints are traced from tPrimefaces and the asterisk should be rendered automatically

Answer (score 0):

That is a nice to have feature that doesn't exist (yet).

If you want it implemented, log an enhancement feature.

Or extend bean validation component ;-)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually I have read in this blog that it supports it. I am not sure either to tell you the truth. http://www.codebulb.ch/2015/05/jsf-validation-localization-i18n-by-example-part-1.html

Comment: put all your code in here ;-) to difficult to reply. do not forget web.xml ;) That example should work following that example in the blog. I abandoned the validation constraint stuff, to much issues. be also aware that you need to follow EXACTLY your blog plus what is written in the primefaces user guide...